# Timed Threaded function as an attribute in a class

Tags: python, multithreading, function, class

So I am making a text based adventure game.  I am working on the engine right now and I am stuck after long hours searching for a solution for this problem.

I have a class called use_action.  One of the arguments for that class is a name of a function.  I would like to be able to create this action and have a possible custom function incase the item that calls this use_action does something specific.

The custom function I am working with right now is where the player is hurt and is losing 5 HP every so many seconds.

This should start when he uses a specific item and then stops when he uses the medicine that will link to the stop function.  The problem I have is that the function gets called immediately.  Even though I am trying to call it at the end of a long if else statement.  And then when i get to where i am trying to call it it doesn't call.

I am not posting the whole class as it along with its functions are about 150 lines of code.

```
class use_action(object):
    def __init__(self, function = None):
        self.function = function


pizza_act = use_action(function = mechanics.tmr.start())

#This is located at the end of an if else statement after the player types use . . . 
if self.function != None:
    self.function
else:
    pass
```

From Mechanics:

```
thread_list = []

class TimerClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, function, time):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.function = function
        self.time = time
        thread_list.append(self)

    def run(self):
        while not self.event.is_set():
            self.event.wait( self.time )
            self.function()

    def stop(self):
        self.event.set()

def blank_current_readline():
    # Next line said to be reasonably portable for various Unixes
    (rows,cols) = struct.unpack('hh', fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdout, termios.TIOCGWINSZ,'1234'))

    text_len = len(readline.get_line_buffer())+2

    # ANSI escape sequences (All VT100 except ESC[0G)
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[2K')                         # Clear current line
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A\x1b[2K'*(text_len/cols))  # Move cursor up and clear line
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[0G')                         # Move to start of line



def pizza_poisoned_action():
    # threading.Timer(10, pizza_poisoned_action).start()
    blank_current_readline()
    print "You lost 5 hp."
    initialization.gamer.hp -= 5
    sys.stdout.write('> ' + readline.get_line_buffer())
    sys.stdout.flush()          # Needed or text doesn't show until a key is pressed

tmr = TimerClass(pizza_poisoned_action, 5)
```

Sorry about the length, I tried to only post the relevant stuff for this.  If you think i should post some other piece of code that may be relevant let me know!

Comment: Tip: Classes should use CamelCase. Just to separate it from functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a function, *don't* call it. Or else, you'll be passing the return value.

```
pizza_act = use_action(function = mechanics.test()) #Wrong!
pizza_act = use_action(function = mechanics.test)  #Right
```

Comment: Thank you for that help!  It seems so obvious now.  But I am completely new to programming and started with Hello, World! 3 weeks ago, sometimes the smallest things are that hardest to find answers too :)

Comment: Hahaha, well, there's a start to everything. You're welcome! Keep learning!